# I am unsure of how to access a persistence entity from a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, persistence

I am just learning Java EE, I have created a Persistence entity for a User object, which is stored in the database. I am now trying to create a JSP page that will allow a client to enter a new User object into the System. I am unsure of how the JSP page interacts with the User facade, the tutorials are confusing me a little.

This is the code for the facade:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add User to System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Add User</h2>
    <h3>Please fill out the details to add a user to the system</h3>
    <form action="">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br />
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="name"><br />
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br />
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address"><br />
        <label>Type:</label>
        <select name="type">
            <option>Administrator</option>
            <option>Member</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add"/>
        <input type="reset" value="clear" />
    </form>
</body>
```

This is the code I have to add a new User object within the User facade class:

```
@Stateless
public class CinemaUserFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MonashCinema-warPU")
    private EntityManager em;

public void create(CinemaUser cinemaUser) {
    em.persist(cinemaUser);
}
```

I am finding it a little difficult to get my head around the whole MVC thing, getting there but would appreciate it if someone could turn the light on for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP is the **view** here. Your `User` entity is the **model** here. What's missing form the "MVC"? Right, the **controller** is missing. You need to develop (or introduce) a controller yet. Is this homework? Then probably just a simple `Servlet` is enough. But if this is the real work, then I recommend to have a look for a real MVC framework to ease all the work, for example Sun JSF (JavaServer Faces).

**See also**:

- [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732)
- [Beginning and Intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html)